# Joining two objects in firebase in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase structure like this

[image]

I'm looking to combine two firebase objects , ie details of user (address, phone) and the details of a order by a key.

But I'm not used to NoSQL and can't figure how to join the objects to display orders.